# Python trying to get length of sublist but get length of string on occasion. Need a work around

Tags: python, string, list

I'm writing a script to search a database for filters and compare the result to an xlsx file thats given to me. due to the format of the given xlsx my filter list sometimes contains a sublist of strings and sometimes a string in the same position. When I get to the actual comparisons I try to check the length of the sublist to run checks specific to the sublists using this code

```
if len(filters[x][1])>1:
```

the filters list is constructed using this block of code

```
while(tpSheet.cell(i,0).value!=''):
    filterNum = tpSheet.cell(i,0).value.split(':')
    if tpSheet.cell(i,2).value.startswith('in'):
        temp = tpSheet.cell(i,2).value[3:].replace(' ','').replace('in',',').split(',')
    filters.append([filterNum[0],[tpSheet.cell(i,1).value,temp[1]],[temp[0],temp[2]]])
else:
    filters.append([filterNum[0],[tpSheet.cell(i,1).value],tpSheet.cell(i,2).value])
i+=1
```

I'm not quite sure how to differentiate between lists and strings for this purpose

Comment: Look up how to check the type of an object?  It's not that hard.

Comment: I actually tried isinstance a few times as well as type but had no luck with either one but more experimentation is probably required

Comment: Even better, post your failing attempt as an [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this example will help you sort through your type discrimination:

test = [123, None, "123", [123, "123"] ]

```
for item in test:
    if isinstance(item, int):
        print item, "is an integer"
    elif isinstance(item, str):
        print item, "is a string"
    elif isinstance(item, list):
        print item, "is a list"
    else:
        print item, "is something else"
```

Output:

```
123 is an integer
None is something else
123 is a string
[123, '123'] is a list
```